# Cannot Display localstorage Array in <a> Tags

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to retrieve and display my localstorage array into the 'a' tags in the

```
<ul id="menu_container1">
```

However, my current code doesn't seem to be working.

Also, would there be a way to automatically create new 'a' tags if there are more values in the 'journey' array than 'a' tags available?

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="menu">
<ul id="menu_container1">
         <li><a href="#" id="firstpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="secondpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="thirdpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="fourthpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="fifthpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="sixthpage">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
var journey = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('journey'))||[];journey.push(location.protocol + 
'//' + location.host + location.pathname);
localStorage.setItem('journey', JSON.stringify(journey));

// This is what isn't working at the moment
$('#menu_container1 a').JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('journey'));
```

Comment: Why not just have an empty <ul> element and just dynamically create the <a> links and add them.  That way you always have the correct number of elements.

Comment: @James Black How would I go about dynamically adding new links?

Comment: I tend to create DOM elements and then just append it to the parent element, but the best approach depends on what you are doing with each link (is there any onclick events to capture, for example).

Comment: @JamesBlack At the moment I just need to display the data, however it would be useful to have an 'id' value for each newly created link.

Comment: What I do is use some unique start (mylist_link_#) and replace # with the index of that item.  That way they are unique, and you can find it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an element at the end of a container by using these jquery functions:

1. `$(container).append(element)`
2. `$(element).appendTo(container)`
   You could, for example, create a new link with `$('menu_container1).append('<a>' + localStorage.getItem('journey') + '</a>')`
   You can iterate over the values of the storage this way:

   for (var i=0; i<=localStorage.length-1; i++)
   {
       var key = localStorage.key(i);
       var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
   }

Comment: The example works, however it inserts all the journey array data into one <a> tag. Is there an 'each' function that could insert one item into each <a> tag?

Comment: Sure my code is for one iteration ! Don't you know how to iterate over an array with JS ? If so just google it !

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but the iteration I have made repeats the whole array instead of each value:    $.each(journey , function(i, val) {
 $('#menu_container1').append('<li class="test"><a>' + localStorage.getItem('journey') + 
 '</a></li>');
 }); Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have tried your iteration, but again it repeats the whole array by the number of values in it, instead of separating the individual values: for (var i=0; i<=localStorage.length-1; i++)
        {
           var key = localStorage.key(i);
           var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
           $('#menu_container1').append('<li class="test"><a>' + val + 
    '</a></li>');
        }

Comment: Sorry I didn't read very well your question. You have only one value in your local storage: the journey array. You just have to iterate over this array.